# Bootstrap form fields don't stay in containing div

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to make a bootstrap form that looks good on web and mobile.  It seems like the straightforward markup doesn't work well.  It's an angular app, but I don't think angular figures in...

One problem is if I try to contain several fields by a div in order to apply a background color, the fields aren't contained, spilling off the left side of the div.

Another problem, related I think, is that the fields appear on mobile with 0px left and right margins, which doesn't look too good.

Here's the markup:

in index .html:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>My BS App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h3 class="text-muted">My BS App</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div ng-view></div>
```

That angular view directive causes the form to be included as follows...

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="parentForm" role="form" novalidate mb-submit="save()">
    <fieldset>
        <div ng-repeat="parent in family.parents()">
            <legend>{{parent.firstName}} {{parent.lastName}}</legend>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="parent.list" ng-model="parent.list">List parent</input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="background-color:red;">Why don't I contain the following?

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="First name" name="firstName" class="form-control" ng-model="parent.firstName" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" name="lastName" class="form-control" ng-model="parent.lastName" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And here's the bad result:  see how fields spill off to the left?

On Web....

[image]

About what it looks like on mobile...

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing the `<div class="row">` tags wrapped around your `<div class="form-group">` tags. Both classes have negative left and right margins, which are being combined by the nested tags.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  Is there a way I can do that and still have the checkboxes sharing the row with the text inputs?  Trying to use the span tags has added a lot of complexity.

Comment: @user3245272: You should be able to use the standard `col-md-*` classes within a `form-group`.

Answer (score 2):

[Example here](http://www.bootply.com/132907).

Add a

```
<div class="col-md-12">
```

After your

```
<div class="row">
```

in the `div` containing the `background-color:red;`.

For example:

```
<div style="background-color:red;">Why don't I contain the following?
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input type="text" placeholder="First name" name="firstName" class="form-control" ng-model="parent.firstName" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" name="lastName" class="form-control" ng-model="parent.lastName" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I chose the other answer which achieved the good result by removing markup.

Answer (score -1):

Compare your code with the correct code of bootstrap documentation

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms